# How to render a mesh transparent with a color on its edges only, with nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, transparency

I would like to have my object transparent, with a color only on the edges, would someone know how to do this? I am starting with the nodes, if anyone can help with some guidelines I would really appreciate ;-)

EDIT:

I was looking for something like the hand in Kinectimals :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what engine you are using.

Comment: @cegaton : there are 7 upvotes for the engine, and you erased my edit :) Didn't they want to know if it is a mac/pc? Or the version of blender? Otherwise, I don't know what they refer to for the "engine".

Comment: @Paul Engine refers to cycles or blender internal. The computer OS or blender version will not make a difference for this answer. The render engine will. The answer I wrote works on Cycles.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

EDIT:

Here's an example using layer weight/fresnel to control the transparency:

[image]

So how does it work?

The Fresnel value on the **[Layer Weight](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/layer_weight.html)** controls the mix of emission and transparency.

[image]

But you can see right through the mesh at the back side of the object. So you need to limit the rendering to only the part of the geometry first seen by the camera, and make the back faces transparent. That's what the Light path node and Transparent depth is for.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks. It looks good. I was looking for something like the hand in Kinectimals : http://www.vgchartz.com/games/pics/kinectimals_19745.jpg

Comment: wow, thank you very much cegaton, it looks great.

Comment: Is it possible to use the 'backfacing' output of the Geometry node as an alternative to that Light Path node? Maybe it gives a similar result at slightly less computational cost

Comment: @R.Navega please use the big blue "Ask Question" link at the top of the page for new questions.

Comment: Let me rephrase: I affirm that 'backfacing' should have the same result as that Light Path factor, but directly plugged to the Mix shader factor.