# How to render a wireframe & glow lines effect on a house?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, transparency

I would like to render this kind of effect:

[image: sample of desired effect]

I would like to render it on a house. The view should be at the top, and the edges of each wall should be a glowing line. I tried the technique from this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes) but the result is not good with my house. Is a way to create this effect?

With a low layer weight, we barely see the house (only the walls inside):
[image: layer weight at .005, house is not visible]

With a higher layer weight:
[image: layer weight at .15, house is not a wireframe]

I am looking for the wireframe effect as on the right, in Edit mode:
[image: desired wireframe effect]

The blend is here : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36004

Comment: Any particular reason why you haven't updated your Blender? It really does help to have the latest version, especially if you're using tutorials or asking questions on forums :-) Sorry for being so nitpicky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it is by adding a wireframe modifier to your building, for those shots where you want the wireframe.

[image]

instant success:

[image]

But don't apply it, else it will modify and change all the geometry of the object. You can disable it from modifying the object by pressing the little eye symbol.

The glow effect could be achieved using composition and a slight influence of the blur node. Or read similar QA threads on this site for suggestions: [Glow with depth in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender)