# How to hide invisible parts in a translucent mesh?

Tags: mesh

It's a tricky question.
I have this ghost mosquito mesh, and my goal is to only render the verticies which are currently visible from the camera view. It's an animation so cutting the invisible parts off is not an optiton.
Is there a node or some masking trick what you can suggest?
Thanks a lot! :)

[image]

Comment: Why is the shader translucent then? Do you need to see what is behind the mosquito? If not you can achieve the same look with Fresnel and opaque surface. You can then composite it transparently onto some background if the mosquito needs to be see-through.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28422/1853

Comment: Oh, thanks for the fast reply, my friend! That's exactly what I was looking for. You are amazing! :)
Actually I expressed myself in a wrong way, I did use the fresnel, but I missed the transparency depth-less than combo.