# How to achieve a microbe/bacteria material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I want to make this texture:

[image: Blue texture]

So far I have done:

[image: My green texture]

This is my adjustment:

[image: My adjustment]

How to improve my material?

Comment: You shouldn't place a Lighten node between the Glossy BSDF and the mix shader. It spits out a color output which doesn't respond to the correct input for your mix node.
Also I'd recommend you place your noise Fac output in the displacement input of the Material output instead of the 'normal procedure' but that's just my opinion

Comment: Aside from already mentioned, it looks like you're searching something like [emissive material on the corners and transparent in the middle](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes). The difference is that in your case you want to add also some bumps on top of that - either with bump mapping or with actual geometry or with new experimental subdivisions.