# Rendering transparent body and opaque edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I want to create a material for an object such that the body is semi-transparent and only the border of the object is opaque or darker. Is it possible to develop a shader for this ? Or do we have to do through only compositing?

Comment: If you want to have the edges shaded and not the faces, maybe you should consider applying a modifier to the mesh: [wireframe modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html), then applying the material normally.

Comment: I don't want all the interior edges to be visible either. Just the outermost edges (borders of the object) to be dark and rest of the object to be semi-transparent.

Comment: although "the border" is a fuzzy concept in 3d meshes, blender has freestyle that can render edges in a lot of ways, but it uses "linestyles" fro them, not regular "materials" as you could define for regular rendering...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to render a mesh transparent with a color on its edges only, with nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes/28423#28423)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: **I understand that the question might actually be about the visual *borders* of the object (the ones usually highlighted using the freestyle pass), not the *edges* of the mesh.**

I'll however leave my (unfitting) answer below in case somebody else is looking for a solution more similar to this.

---

A solution could be duplicating your object, then:

- assigning a transparent material to copy #1 (the greenish material in my example)
- for copy #2, using a [wireframe modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html) and applying the material shown in the nodes setup below, which mixes a full white transparency and a diffuse shader, using the ["Transparent depth" input](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/light_path.html#outputs) as a mixing factor.

As you can see, back edges are hidden in this setup. You can display them by simply using a diffuse shader (*i.e.* bypassing the mix shader).

[image: Transparent object, shaded wireframe]

Be aware that this won't work if the object is seen through another transparent object: all the wires will be hidden in this case.

Comment: Duplicating is a good idea. I'll check if something can be done like that.

Comment: A workaround solution for shading only the borders could be using only one mesh (it needs to be **highly subdivided!**) and a material made of a `mixer shader` with: {Top shader: `transparent`} {Bottom shader: `diffuse`} {Fac: `Fresnel`, IOR = 1.03}. This will shade only those faces that are almost perpendicular to the line of sight.

Comment: This would work under the assumption that only the faces close to borders are almost perpendicular to the line of sight right, if I understood your idea correctly?

Comment: Yes, any other topology which is not at the borders but that sharply points towards the camera would be sketched