# Model a transparent body

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I created a human body shape in blender. I need to show veins or organes in that body but still be able to reconise that it's a body. I tried glass but a glass body look's strange and is full of reflections. Any idea in wish direction to take this ? I'm trying to get something kind of like that :

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28423/1853

Comment: @cegaton yes that would be the answer but how he would get the same result, if your node stup there is showing the edges a harder and semitransparent color and the rest transparent in the object?

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid just use the proposed node setup on the outer layer of the skin. The other objects could use other materials depending on the desired effect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Yjt.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA4a2.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a mesh transparent with a color on its edges only, with nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes)

Comment: Doesn't look like a Duplicate Q to me. I don't think this is the ghost effect done with fresnel. This looks more like a negative film effect where shadows are the bright parts. Probably a better solution to this using compositing nodes and render layers than shader nodes.

Comment: Try the AO node in 2.8 that you can invert to drive the transparency and color to get this "x-ray" negative film effect.

Answer (score 20):

[image: final]

This method is working suprisingly well in EEVEE. It's fully real time (fast, very fast). In Cycles also. And it is very flexible.

[image: eevee]

### Material setup

Basically it is mix between Emission and Emission Transparent shader.

I've used **Normal input** to drive **Facing Blend** value, this is for making "highlights". **Color Ramp** is for fine tuning intensity of those highlights. By rotating sphere inside Normal node you can achieve many interesting setups. The one from example is pointing downwards.

[image: Normal]

**Fresnel** is used to make a bit of an outline around object.

[image: nodes]

### EEVEE

To make it work in EEVEE you need to change material **Blend Mode** to **Alpha Blend** and turn of (if you need it) **Show Backface**.

[image: eevee]

### Cycles

For **Backfacing** in **Cycles** you can use this setup. It's not working as well as in **EEVEE** but it is still good.

[image: cycles]

Answer (score 5):

Using a matcap works in eevee and cycles, allows fast renders and simple setup.

I'm also using the same matcap image as a mask for opacity and color.

[image: matcap setup]