# Is it possible to shade objects in Cycles based on Z gradient, to highlight/darken edges?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I'd like to shade the edges of my objects darker, like a toon shader, based on abrupt Z depth transitions to neighboring pixels -- in other words wherever the Z gradient is high, darken the image. I imagine that can be done in the compositor (?), but can it be done in object space in the material shader editor?

Something like this (not from Blender):
[image: Real images on left, Z-edge shaded on right]

Comment: Can you show an example of result?

Comment: Added a couple of samples of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried freestyle?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192498/is-it-possible-to-create-realtime-outline-effect-in-eevee-only-with-shaders/192538#192538

Comment: I have tried using Fresnel but that's only based on the normal (dot product of normal and eye vectors), not Z distance discontinuity, so it doesn't pick up edges of a flat object. Works OK for spheres though.

Comment: I've tried enabling Freestyle but it never seems to do anything. Probably something I'm missing in the setup?