# How do you keep parts from showing through the skin on a transparent character?

Tags: shaders, transparency

I'm currently making a character who will be mostly transparent.  I've gotten the face done, but I have an issue.  The teeth, eyes, and inner mouth are visible from behind.  I want them to be hidden unless you're looking directly at them.  Is there a way to do this?

Images of what I have so far of the character for reference.

[image][image]

Comment: Use the transparent depth information (from the light path node) to control the transparency, so that only the first surface seen by the camera is visible, refer to the last image on this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes

Answer (score 0):

Materials in Blender can be set to be transparent, so that light can pass through any objects using the material. Transparency is controlled using an “alpha” channel, where each pixel has an additional value, range 0-1, in addition to its RGB color values.

[Transparency](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/properties/transparency.html#:%7E:text=Materials%20in%20Blender%20can%20be,to%20its%20RGB%20color%20values.)

So if you want an object to be transparent you could change (this can also be animated / keyed) the material and or alpha level of those objects you want to be transparent or solid.

Here's a detail link with a tutorial along with an example / walk through showing you how to do this.

[Alpha / Transparency instructions](https://www.katsbits.com/codex/alpha/)

[Video Link explaining Alpha / Transparency](https://youtu.be/esIKF8WvaVg)