# How to make an object transparent but give it color to its edges using nodes?

Tags: rendering, mesh, node-editor, transparency

I'm pretty new here and I have little experience with Blender, and I'm still struggling to understand how nodes work.

However, I like Blender a lot and I'd like to ask for help to achieve the effect you see in the attached image. A colored edge with transparent mesh. This effect should be achieved no matter from which angle you look at the model.

[image]

I saw a post with an answer to something similar using an old version of Blender and I'd like to see if anybody has a different approach to it using the principled bsdf shader, since I know it combines some of the nodes this solution uses.

Here is the link to that same post: [How to render a mesh transparent with a color on its edges only, with nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/how-to-render-a-mesh-transparent-with-a-color-on-its-edges-only-with-nodes?newreg=c9121f5a9b7445438b07ac964598dd66)

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can use a Principled BSDF, but you still have to Mix it with a Transparent Shader using a Fresnel as a Mix factor as outlined in the linked answer (The Principled BSDF's built-in alpha won't cut it).